# Basic validation / checkbox and text field

Tags: javascript

I am trying to validate "mytextinput" only if the checkbox with the id="checkbox" is checked. No luck! Tried these variations of script:

```
    if (myform.mytextinput.value=="" && document.getElementById("checkbox").checked) {
    alert ('Please enter something!');
    return false;}
```

---

```
    if (myform.mytextinput.value=="" && document.getElementById("checkbox").checked==true) {
    alert ('Please enter something!');
    return false;}
```

---

```
    if (myform.mytextinput.value=="" || document.getElementById("checkbox").checked) {
    alert ('Please enter something!');
    return false;}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make it this way. The validation of your input will only executed if your checkbox is checked.

```
if(document.getElementById("checkbox").checked){
        if (myform.mytextinput.value == "") {
            alert("Please enter something!");
            return false;
        }

    //... more validation
    }
```

In your solution you're validating the checkbox AND your input but possibly it's not necessary to check the input because the checkbox isn't checked.

### [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/276X3/)

Comment: Thank you!! A lot! Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

If you want the users to write something in the textfield, but only validate if the checkbox with id `checkbox` is checked, this should work:

```
if (myform.mytextinput.value.length < 1 && document.getElementById("checkbox").checked) {
    alert ('Please enter something!');
    return false;
}
```